# Relation between the diffusion coefficients

Tags: thermodynamics, diffusion, viscosity

My course is giving me a strange relation I have difficulties to understand. In the context of thermodynamics and evolution, we define:

1. The **mass diffusion flux**: (Newton's law)
   $$J_{M_d} = -D\frac{dc}{dy}$$
2. The **energy diffusive flux**: (Fourier's law)
   $$J_{E_d} = -\alpha \frac{d(\rho u)}{dy}$$

3. The **momentum diffusion flux**: (Fick's law)
   $$J_{E_d} = -\nu \frac{d(\rho v)}{dy}$$

After introducing this, I read:
[image: The relations alpha/nu = 1 and D/nu = 1]

(sorry for not computing those equations, it would have taken me ages)

I don't expect anyone to verify those infernal fractions, I'm only interested in the two results:
$$\frac{\alpha}{\nu} = 1$$
$$\frac{D}{\nu} = 1$$
Naturally, I understand:
$$\color{red}{\alpha = \nu = D}$$
Yet, I feel this couldn't be as simple and that I missed something. Is this relation correct ? If yes, in what specific context ? If not, why ?

---

**Edit:** Notice also the sentences in gray:

> The experimental ratio for gases is about 1.3-2.5

Those numbers confirm the fact that those formulas are approximations, right ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, it figures out that those relations are true for **perfect gases only** (you can see it by the $k_B T$ appearing several times for instance). This explains the difference between the experimental relations and the calculated ones.